# How does Solr's MoreLikeThis component internally work to get results?

Tags: solr, full-text-search, morelikethis

I'm new to Apache Solr and am currently exploring/trying to make use of [MoreLikeThis](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis) as a search component (instead of dedicated request handler).  I'm finding difficult to understand clearly on how this works internally to get more-like-this results?

For example, I'm trying to search for the word `java` in one of the document field named `mytextcontentfield`:

> http://localhost/solr/core0/select/?q=mytextcontentfield:java&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&debugQuery=on&mlt=true&mlt.fl=mytextcontentfield

and I could see *moreLikeThis* in the XML response with unique keys of the documents in `name` attribute.

My questions here is, how does Solr internally work/match to find more-like-this documents based on the search keyword `java`?  Any explanation with good example are appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks there's no Solr documentation that explain this feature in detail.

But somehow, after some google, managed to find a write-up on [How MoreLikeThis Works in Lucene](http://cephas.net/blog/2008/03/30/how-morelikethis-works-in-lucene/).